# p-value of the following test

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing, p-value

I have the following problem:

I have $X_1 ... X_n$ ~ Bernoulli(p) independent. 
I also have the following test hypothesis: $H_0: p = p_0$ and $H_1: p > p_0$. I define my test as follows:

$T:$ I refuse $H_0$ in favour of $P_1$ if the number of successes is very high.

Now suppose $p_0 = 0.6$ and $n = 20$, we find that we have 18 successes.

I want to find the p-value of the test.

Now this is what I have done:

$p-value = \mathbb{P}(\sum x_i \geq 18)$ = 0.0005240494 
However confronting it with the command:

```
binom.test(18,20,p=.6,alternative=greater)
```

It is not right (by a factor of 10). My problem is that I am not able to correctly asses what the "number of succession is very high". How do I work around this?

Comment: What is the confidence level and significance level, respectively? Maybe 0.95 and 1-0.95=0.05?

Comment: I don't have that information. I don't think is needed as the purpose of the p-value is to work without one, from my understanding.

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(\sum X_i \geq 18)=0.0036$

Comment: @d.k.o. I see, maybe I messed up my calculation. Still, is this the right way to do it?

Comment: Yes this is the correct way to do it

Answer (score 1):

Letting $K=\sum_i \mathbb{I}(X_i = 1)$ be the number of successes, you have $K \sim \text{Bin}(n,p)$.  Thus, your p-value is:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
p \equiv p(k) 
&\equiv  \mathbb{P}( K \geqslant k | H_0) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{P}( K \geqslant k | K \sim \text{Bin}(n,p_0)) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{r=k}^n \text{Bin}(r|n,p_0). \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

With $p_0=0.6$, $n=20$ and $k=18$ you get the p-value:

$$p = \sum_{r=18}^{20} \text{Bin}(r|20, 0.6) 
= 0.003611472.$$